# Refactor / Rename does not update View Binding references in java

Tags: android-studio, refactoring, rename, android-viewbinding

I have noticed that if I rename an XML file using Android Studio it properly updates code that references the file like "R.layout.file_name" but not view binding references like "FileNameBinding".

Is there a way to do this? I have a project I've inherited and I want to normalize the layout file names because the prior developer was not consistent. I know I could probably write a PowerShell script to do the work but it would be great if Android Studio would do it for me.